# Flutter Project is not recognizing my Android Emulator or connected device

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, emulation

I am trying to build Flutter Project but once I open Flutter Project in Android Studio, project is not recognizing Android Emulator (AVD) or connected device. But When I open simple Android Project, it is recognizing emulator and device. Flutter sdk, flutter plugins, dart plugins everything was installed as it was shown, but I can't fix it. I am just starting learning Flutter, what's wrong with it?[Android Studio Emulator for Flutter Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRK65.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot this with `flutter devices`. Probably it will be empty. Here are some instructions related to it: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#set-up-your-android-device

Setting your `ANDROID_HOME` or `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` variable may help.